# Некорректная работа joda-time?

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

Почему код:

```
Date birthday;

    try
    {
        birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.04.2010");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        birthday = new Date(1990, 02, 05);
    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "DEBUG: " + new DateTime(birthday).getDayOfMonth() + " " + new DateTime(birthday).getMonthOfYear(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

выдает "DEBUG: 31 3" вместо логичного "DEBUG: 1 4" ?

Comment: Время ещё в дебаг поместите. Похоже ли будет на Вашу временную зону?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже в такой строке "01.04.2010" не содержится время, поэтому оно по умолчанию принимается за 00:00:00.000, а йода учитывает часовой пояс которой есть в системе и вычитает его, поэтому дата уходит назад.
Вобщем, закостылил на пока так:

```
birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(cursor.getString(birthdayColumnIndex) + " 23:59:00");
```